# Cant launch Linux(I've tried many methods)

Tags: boot, 12.10, wubi

I'm a newbie in Linux, so I don't know how to fix these problems.

I have Intel core i5 , 3 GB RAM and nVidia GeForce 310m(512 mb)

I really want to try Linux, But I can't even launch it. When I boot from CD, I tried to enter **,,Try Linux,,** And **,,Install Linux,,**, but when launch screen with Ubuntu logo appears, after five minutes dots stop blinking. I was waiting for an hour, but nothing changed.

Then I've created a boot USB, but I had the same problem.

So I tried to install it through Windows 8. I installed wubi and when I boot Linux, the black screen of loading appeared, and after some minutes it stopped(I do not remember at what moment)

I also tried to change mode to **,,nomodeset,,** but nothing changed.

I don't know what to do :(

Comment: Please identify your hardware, from windows, in particular what video card are you using. You almost certainly have an incompatible videocard, but without identifying the card hard to know if you can fix it or will need a new card. Your other option would be to try Ubuntu in Virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

The way I either try or install is download the Linux you want from Distrowatch. After download put the iso image on your desktop. Next you must get Unetbootin. Next launch Unetbootin and load the iso image to a USB device. When the iso image is complete and the message REBOOT appears then you reboot. Upon the start of the boot process continue to press the F12 key until TRY LINUX or DEFAULT appears, that's it.